# How to model Chemical Kinetics when both ligand and receptors are moving?

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics, chemical-biology

I am not a chemistry student but trying to understand something that requires Chemistry. My problem is that when we have Ligand and receptor reaction to form complex we normally assume as [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_(biochemistry))

"In protein-ligand binding, the ligand is usually a molecule which produces a signal by binding to a site on a target protein."

My issue is do we have chemical kinetics giving us some clue when both of Ligand and receptor is moving, of course this is something like a reaction in a solution but **I am majorly concerned with probability that Ligand be able to bind with receptor when both of them are in random motion and any literature related to that.** 
I may not that much clear in my presentation, but it will be really helpful if any kind of support be given.

Comment: This is a non-issue. All molecules are always in random motion. Still, chemical reactions do occur sometimes.

Comment: This should be describable by chemical kinetics as $\ce{L + P <=> LP}$ where the ligand L, protein receptor P and when bound the complex LP are in equilibrium. The equilibrium constant determines what fraction of the ligand is bound.  The reaction is likely so slow that how quickly the molecules diffuse is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, the probability of the ligand to be able to bind with receptor is affected by the intermolecular interactions of both.